# Get the training data from the trained model's pickle file

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Can I get the training data used for training a model in sklearn from the pickle file of the trained model?

Comment: You most certainly can not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we can retrieve the training data used for developing a model from the pickle file of the trained model.

Trained model is only a representation of relation of the dependent variable to the independent variables used for model which will help us in predicting the dependent variable value for any new record of independent variable that comes in.

Hope this helps.